# How to get the compiler to disallow method invocation on upper-bound reference

Tags: java, generics, io

I know that the following syntax is not legal:

```
void dolist2(List<? extends Number> list) {
    list.add(new Integer(3));
}
```

But I do not know how the compiler knows it is not legal. If I look at the source code of List.java I see:

`boolean add(E e);`

I see *nothing special at all* about this declaration, not even an annotation like @IllegalWhenInvokedOnUpperBoundReference. How does the compiler know to enforce this restriction? How do I place similar restrictions on my own classes?

Comment: Presumably you are aware that `new Integer(3)` is adding a boxed integer with value 3 to the list. It's not allocating three elements of something.

Comment: @Bathsheba actually no boxing conversion is taking place in the expression new Integer(3). All you've done is wrapped the value, not boxed it. To get boxing you would have to write `Integer I = 3` so that wrapping occurs implicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It knows is because `Integer` is not an instance of `? extends Number`. `? extends Number` means: an unknown type which is or extends Number. Since the type is unknown, the compiler cannot tell that Integer is a valid type, and thus refuses to compile.

You can't add a String to a `List<Integer>` either, because the compiler knows that String doesn't extend Integer. Type checking is one of the roles of the compiler.

You seem to think that this is something special that List has and your code can't have. It's not. It's just a rule of the generic types:

```
public class Whatever<T> {
    public void foo(T e) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Whatever<? extends Number> w = new Whatever<Integer>();
        w.foo(new Integer(4)); // won't compile
    }
}
```

Comment: um... Integer is a subclass of Number. So I can write `void dolist1(List<? super Number> list) { list.add(new Integer(3)); }`

Comment: Yes, but super and extends don't mean the same thing. `List<? super Number>` means a List of some unknow type that is Number or is a superclass or superinterface of Number. So it could be, for example a List<Number> or a List<Object>. And all these lists accept an Integer. That's why you can add an Integer. The compiler can guarantee that Integer is a valid type.

Comment: OK, thanks to both of you for the help. I was confused because in every case I've seen where this behavior is explained they refer to the add method of collections. This would explain why the remove method is `remove(Object o)` and not `remove(e E)`, but the add method is `add(e E)` and not `add(Object o)`..

Comment: Actually, can I summarize this whole discussion by stating that the compiler will not allow invocations where the return value would have lower bound type arguments, and not allow invocations where one of the formal method arguments would have upper bound type arguments? It seems clear when I read it that way..

Comment: @Mishax: and you've discovered the PECS (Producer `extends`, Consumer `super`) rule.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler knows that you can pass List of any subtype of `Number` in `List<? extends Number>`. So, you can pass a `List<Double>`, `List<Float>` any thing.

Now, since it can't confirm for sure which type the method gets, if you add anything to the list, it is not type safe, and will result in Heap Pollution. So, the below statement:

```
list.add(new Integer(3));
```

is not safe. You might be adding `Integer` to a `List<Double>`. Since those types aren't compatible, that will fail at runtime. So, compiler gives you an error. This concept is well known as ***PECS***(Producer Extends Consumer Super)

---

**Suggested Read:**

- [Angelika Langer - Java Generics FAQS](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [How do I define a Generic Type](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ002)
  - [Wildcard Instantiation](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ301)
- [Oracle Generics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is correct and I understand the "why" of it. What I am asking is "how does the compiler look at the add method and know that that add method can't be used that way" and "how can I use this mechanism in my own code"

Comment: @Mishax. I don't understand. What do you mean by using the mechanism in your own code? This is a generics feature. What kind of behaviour do you want? It would be better to explain with your concrete code.

Comment: @Mishax. You can make your class generic too. And this feature will be applicable to your class.

Comment: I do not consider the "add" method to be a *language feature*. I consider it to be part of the API, and the collections framework specifically. Your comment is starting to confirm the sinking feeling I was already having, namely that this is hard-coded into the compiler, and that the function is not available to me. Which is unfortunate.

Comment: Can you show me an example? This is what I am looking for, how do I write my own class and my own method, and have the compiler prevent invocation on a reference that is upper-bound.

Comment: @Mishax: read my answer for an example of code that has this behavior. It's a generics feature, and applies to all the generic types, whoever wrote them. It's not at all hard-coded into the compiler, and it's not part of the API, and it's not specific to the collections framework.

Comment: @Mishax. So your main issue is how to write a generic class? You can refer to JBNizet's answer for an example.

Comment: @Mishax. I suggest you to go through the link I added in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In java generics, there are two kinds of bounds for wildcards:

- `? extends Y`
- `? super Y`

The first form, `extends`, tells you and the compiler that what you have is guaranteed to be a subclass of `Y` but you have no guarantee of what subclass... Thus you can always *read* values from an `extends` as they are guaranteed to be *downcastable* to type `Y`. You cannot write to such a wildcard as you have no guarantees that the type is compatible with the type you are passing.

The second form, `super`, tells you and the compiler that the class is guaranteed to take at most a `Y`. The values will be happy to take instances of type `Y` because they are expecting either `Y` itself *or* a superclass of `Y`... Thus you can always `write` values to a `super` wildcard.

Here is a code example using the two types of wildcard:

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {
  for (T t: src) dest.add(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Box<T> {

    private T t;          

    public void set(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public T get() {
        return t;
    }

    public <U extends Number> void inspect(U u){
        System.out.println("T: " + t.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("U: " + u.getClass().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>();
        integerBox.set(new Integer(10));
        integerBox.inspect("some text"); // error: this is still String!
    }
}
```

compilation fails, since our invocation of inspect  includes a String:

```
Box.java:21: <U>inspect(U) in Box<java.lang.Integer> cannot
  be applied to (java.lang.String)
                        integerBox.inspect("10");
                                  ^
1 error
```

Source:Java Tutorial[Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)